# Override property with own setter in Singleton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class `ViewController.m` where I want to set a property of my other class `Singleton.m` which should automatically be saved to the `NSUserDefaults`.

I think I have to make the property in `Singleton.m` readonly and override the setter, but is this the best way? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Why make it read-only?

Comment: so you have to use the custom setter and not be able to use the dot notation

Comment: Dot notation is just syntactic sugar for the calling setters and getters, there is no reason to have such a restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the property read-only does not make much sense (if I understand your problem correctly). What you probably want is:

- override the `init` method to load the property from the user defaults when the
  singleton is instantiated,
- override the default *setter* to save the properties value to the user defaults when a new value is set.

Example: **Singleton.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject

+(instancetype)sharedSingleton;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL myBoolProp;

@end
```

**Singleton.m:**

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

static NSString *kMyBoolPropKey = @"MyBoolProp";

+(instancetype)sharedSingleton
{
    static Singleton *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myBoolProp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kMyBoolPropKey];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setMyBoolProp:(BOOL)myBoolProp
{
    _myBoolProp = myBoolProp;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:myBoolProp forKey:kMyBoolPropKey];
}

@end
```

(Note that both

```
[[Singleton sharedSingleton] setMyBoolProp:...];
[Singleton sharedSingleton].myBoolProp = ...;
```

will call the custom setter method `setMyBoolProp`.)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, but it says `_myBoolProb` is undeclared and I should replace it with `myBoolProb`. Doing so leads me to the warning `Local declaration hides instance variable`.
Oh, thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @user2414460: Then you probably have a `@synthesize myBoolProb` in your code. You can *remove* that statement, because the new compilers generate `@synthesize myBoolProb = _myBoolProb`  automatically.

Comment: Do I have to declare the property in the .m file? At the moment I have it in the .h file

Comment: @user2414460: That's correct. The property is declared in the .h file.

Comment: But it still says _myBoolProp is undeclared (I deleted the @synthesize)

Comment: @user2414460: I have now copied the complete Singleton.h + Singleton.m from my test project into the answer. That compiles without errors. Perhaps you can start from that.

Comment: I copied your code but still get the error.
I tried running it when I write `self.myBoolProp`
 but that makes an infinite loop of `setMyBoolProp`

Comment: @user2414460: Yes, using self.myBoolProp inside the setter method will create an infinite loop, that's why the (automatically synthesized) instance varialbe _myBoolProp is used instead. - Frankly, I do not know what to do. I am fairly sure that the above code is correct, and it compiles in my test environment. It should work on all Xcode >= 4.4.

Comment: Maybe because I have a `NSString`, not a `BOOL`
 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44787/discussion-between-martin-r-and-user2414460)