# iOS: Singleton returning null

Tags: ios, singleton

I have a singleton and I pass data to it but it returns null can you please help me in my situation. Thanks in advance :)

Here's my code

**Card.h**

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *fName;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *lName;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *category;

+(Card *)getCard;
```

**Card.m**

```
@synthesize email;
@synthesize fName;
@synthesize lName;
@synthesize category;

static csCard *instance;

+(Card *) getCard
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        if(instance == nil)
        {
            instance = [[Card alloc]init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

- (id) init{

    self.email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"email"];
    self.fName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"firstName"];
    self.lName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"lastName"];
    self.category = @"TestCategory";

    return self;
}
```

and here's my test code to see if it's working

**Test.m**

```
Card *card = [Card getCard];
    [card setEmail:self.emailField.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",card.email);
```

but this code give me (null)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995479/override-property-with-own-setter-in-singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your class like this.

**Card.h**

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *email; //Let the modal be strong property
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *fName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *lName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *category;

+(Card *)getCard;
```

**Card.m**

```
static Card *instance;

+(Card *) getCard
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        if(instance == nil)
        {
            instance = [[Card alloc]init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
- (NSString)email{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"email"];
}

- (void)setEmail:(NSString)email{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setString:email forkey:@"email"];
}
```

No need of overriding init

in your test class

```
Card *card = [Card getCard];
    [card setEmail:self.emailField.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",card.email);
```

Comment: Thanks! so strong is my only problem :)

Comment: BTW thanks for the setter and getter method tip it's really useful :D +100000

Answer (score 0):

```
static csCard *instance;

+(csCard *) getCard
{
@synchronized (self)
{
    if(instance == nil)
    {
        instance = [[csCard alloc]init];
    }
}
return instance;
}
```

Replace it with this code

```
static Card *instance;

 +(Card *) getCard
{
@synchronized (self)
{
    if(instance == nil)
    {
        instance = [[Card alloc]init];
    }
}
return instance;
}
```

The Class name Of the instance Object was wrong and In singleton method,the return datatype was also wrong. I think u will understand what I am saying.

Comment: Ok.Now In test class,at which place you are writing that code(For example :On button click) ?

Comment: And I think that u are writing the code of test class in any of view cycle method i.e On viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear and the reason is that at that time the textfield value will be null because the user didn't input the value.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of what  βhargavḯ sujjested u can modify your code as below because 
in the line `static csCard *instance;` u are using `csCard` i think it is typo so better u can do like this,

```
  #import "Card.h"
  static dispatch_once_t onceDispach;

  @implementation Card
  @synthesize email = _email;
  @synthesize fName;
  @synthesize lName;
  @synthesize category;

   static Card *instance = nil; //change this to Card because this instance which is of type Card

 +(Card *)getCard
  {
     dispatch_once(&onceDispach, ^{
     instance = [[self alloc] init];//careate Card shared object named instance
      });
    return instance;
  }

  - (id) init
  {

      self.email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"email"];
      self.fName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"firstName"];
      self.lName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"lastName"];
      self.category = @"TestCategory";

      return self;
  }
  @end

 - (NSString *)email
   {
      return _email;
   }

 - (void)setEmail:(NSString *)email
  {
    _email = email;
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [userDefault setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
  }
```

in the class where u are using this shared instance use like below

```
  - (void)actionMathodCalled
   {
     Card *card = [Card getCard];
     NSLog(@"before saving to defaults->%@",card.email);
     [card setEmail:@"happyCoding@ymail.com"];
     NSLog(@"after savng to defaults->%@",card.email);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (Card *)instance {
    static Card *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Card alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

It should be work